# Extract Server name from JIRA

Tags: jira

I would like to get the server name(pop/Imap mail server) from JIRA.

I searched the JIRA API and I tried in few ways, but could not do it.

How I can do it?

Comment: Scrape the admin webpage that shows it?

Comment: I want to extract the servername by my coding part. So i used few JIRA API. But didnt get exactly. So could you tell me which jira api is suitable to get the servername from JIRA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this, you will need to first get an instance of the MailServerManager from JIRA, the following Groovy fragment shows how to accomplish this:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.mail.server.MailServerManager

componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
mailServerManager = componentManager.getMailServerManager()
```

To get the Hostname of the SMTP Server for the default SMTPMailServer, the following Groovy fragment shows how:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.mail.server.MailServerManager

componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
mailServerManager = componentManager.getMailServerManager()
mailServer = mailServerManager.getDefaultSMTPMailServer()
return mailServer.getHostname()
```

Getting the hostname of the default POPMailServer is done as followed:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.mail.server.MailServerManager
import com.atlassian.mail.server.SMTPMailServer

componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
mailServerManager = componentManager.getMailServerManager()
mailServer = mailServerManager.getDefaultPopMailServer()
return mailServer.getHostname()
```

The classes in the JIRA API you will want to reference are:

- [OFBizMailServerManager](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/mail/server/managers/OFBizMailServerManager.html#getSmtpMailServers%28%29)
- [MailServer](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-mail/1.16/apidocs/com/atlassian/mail/server/MailServer.html)
- [POPMailServer](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-mail/1.16/apidocs/com/atlassian/mail/server/PopMailServer.html)
- [SMTPMailServer](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-mail/1.16/apidocs/com/atlassian/mail/server/SMTPMailServer.html)